# Is char signed or unsigned on OS X C++

Tags: c++, macos

Is char signed or unsigned on OS X.

I put the following snippet together to test, but was wondering how to tell for sure?

```
char a(0x80);           //fill most sig bit 
unsigned char b(0x80);  //fill most sig bit

cout<<"char ";
(a==b)? cout<<"is not" : cout<<"is";    //compare most sig bits in diff't chars
cout<<" signed\n";
```

The result was:  `char is signed`

I'd like to know how to find this out without a piece of trick code.

Comment: Why do you need to know this?  If you need a signed char, use `signed char`, and if you need an unsigned char, use `unsigned char`.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield There's nothing wrong with theory and the pursuit of knowledge. It seems like a fine question to me.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield, I was reading some code written by others that was doing bit manipulation with 'plain' char.  So I was asking to find out if you had to worry about the value of the most significant bit causing problems if char is signed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the value of `std::numeric_limits<char>::is_signed`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
  std::cout << "char "
            << (std::numeric_limits<char>::is_signed ? "is" : "is not")
            << " signed.\n";
  return 0;
}
```